# Is this proof for a linear subspace correct?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, proof-writing, linear-transformations, solution-verification

I have the following exercise and wanted to know if my proof is correct:
Let $V$ and $W$ be vector spaces over $\mathbb R$ and $\phi: V \to W $ a linear transformation. Show that the image $Im(\phi)$ is a linear subspace of $W$.

**Proof**:
Let $w_1, w_2 \in Im (\phi)$ and let $r_1, r_2 \in \mathbb R$ be arbitrary. In order to proof that $Im(\phi)$ is a linear subspace of $W$ we need to show that all linear combinations of $r_1*w_1 + r_2*w_2$ are in $W$.

Since $w_1, w_2 \in Im(\phi)$ there exists $v_1, v_2$ such that $w_1=\phi(v_1)$ and $w_2=\phi(v_2)$. Therefore $r_1*w_1 + r_2*w_2 = r_1*\phi(v_1) + r_2*\phi(v_2)$. Since $\phi$ is a linear transformation we have that $r_1*\phi(v_1) + r_2*\phi(v_2) = \phi(v_1*r_1) + \phi(v_2*r_2)$ and $\phi(v_1*r_1) + \phi(v_2*r_2)=\phi(v_1*r_1+v_2*r_2)$ and thus for all $w_1, w_2 \in W$ and all $r_1, r_2 \in \mathbb R$ we have that $(r_1*w_1 + r_2*w_2)\in W$.

The one proof step that I am not really sure why (and if) it works is that it follows from the linearity of the function that $r_1*\phi(v_1) + r_2*\phi(v_2) = \phi(v_1*r_1) + \phi(v_2*r_2)$. However I have seen this before in other proofs, but don't fully understand it.

Comment: $\phi(r_iv_i)=r_i\phi(v_i)$ follows from the definition of $\phi$ being linear.  What is your definition of linear?

Comment: Mistake: In $W$ the scalar multiplication is from the left and in $V$ it from right??

Comment: What you need to show is that any linear combination of elements of $Im(\phi)$ is in $Im(\phi)$, not in $W$ as you say in the first paragraph of the proof.

Comment: @Javi good point, thanks